# Handle custom exceptions in Java process builder

Tags: java, process

I have a scenario wherein I wanna monitor the execution status of a process.  I use Java process builder but what happens is when there is custom exception the exit status is 0. Is it possible to differentiate successful completion and the custom exception...  Is there any other way other than process builder in Java?

Comment: Exit status 0 would indicate the process completed *without* any error or exception. I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: Do you mean exit status of your program or `exitValue()` from the `Process` instance?

Comment: You can specify exit code by `System.exit(1);`. Note that it will also close your program, so do it as last statement in `main`.

Comment: Yes..  Exit value returns 0.

Comment: I understand the logic why the exit value is 0.  My requirement is exit value should be 0 only if the program runs successfully without any exceptions. Is there a way (with or without using processbuilder,)  I can get the exit status,  when an custom exception is being caught